# Balanced Payments Integration

Tags: api, plugins, integration, credit-card, balanced-payments

I am trying to integrate Balanced Payments into my website to collect and charge credit cards. I have absolutely no knowledge of how to integrate this into my website (tokenizing, charging, ect.) and I cannot figure out how to do so.

Are there any credit card processor plugins that I can just punch in my Balanced account info and stick it on my website or pre-built ones for Balanced?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually don't have any plugins like the one you are referring to. However, we do have a partnership with Apixchange (https://apixchange.com/), where you can find qualified developers that can integrate the product for you.